Blur SH coefficients of an environment map
my question is about blurring SH coefficients (degree 2) using a Gaussian blur filter.
The SH coefficients, in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 9}$, represent an environment map.
Is it possible to convolve the SH coefficients (instead of passing through the cubemap representation) with a Gaussian blur filter? If so, how can one move to frequency domain the filter?
